# Pi Keeps rebooting

Tags: raspbian, chromium

I have 26 Raspberry Pis that are running slideshows via web browser. The slideshow is a website built on the Webslides Javascript framework with an autorefresh extension on Chromium.

The problem I seem to be intermittently encountering is that I occasionally come in to find that the Pi is sitting on the Raspbian desktop.
Given that I am never present for these failures, I am just notified of them, I have little more than that to go on and I am at wit's end. Is there a reason the Pis might be rebooting?  I have to believe if Chromium was just closing it would show an error message.

I am new to the Raspberry Pi, so I very well could have missed a setting or something. Thanks in advance for the input!

Comment: Your question can be summarized to: "My RasPi suddenly boots. How can I avoid this?" What answer may be possible with this information? Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Comment: Chromium has huge memory usage - I would monitor that. Is your slideshow just showing images?

Comment: Yes, it currently has about 15 images. I don't anticipate it using much more. I could see about a lighter weight browser.

Comment: Don't use a browser, use an app that scrolls images. eg fbi https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2017/02/how-to-display-images-on-raspbian-command-line-with-fbi/

Comment: Either way, in the general case you're going to have to put some logging in place to try to determine what went wrong.  You should already be able to tell from the logs whether or not the device rebooted. Do you start the application on boot?  I'd do that anyway, because then if it reboots (because of a crash or because someone fiddled with the power, whatever) it will restart automatically.

Comment: I don't do it on boot. I lose authentication on the website anyway. I am going to set that up going forward and change to a cookie based authentication instead of session. This should make an automatic boot work for me even if it does restart.